# Toggle Menu with a chain of animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, menu

I am about to code an overlay menu which appears by click, obviously. The thing is, that it's not just a plain colored overlay to impose on the screen. Rather there are certain fade out animations happening to the layout elements, then the menu comes. by clicking on the same button again, the menu disappears, then the elements fade in one after the other.
I managed to realize this up to the point of switching between the two states. How do I switch between the two states?

HTML

```
<div class="menu-contact trans-short">
  <dir class="wrap">
    <!-- 
    these 2 are one button. depending on the state one disappears 
    -->
    <a href="#" class="btn-contact">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-contact-close off">CLOSE</a>
  </dir>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
            var contact;

            // contact button
            $(document).on('click', 'a.btn-contact', function(){
                var contact = true;
            });
            $(document).on('click', 'a.btn-contact-close', function(){
                var contact = false;
            });

            if (contact == true) {

                    // disable scrolling
                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
                    $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // switch to display block
                        $( ".content-wrapper-contact" ).removeClass( "off" );
                    }, 300);

                    // fade out other elements
                    $( '.container' ).addClass( 'blur' );
                    $( ".content-wrapper" ).fadeOut(300);
                    $( ".page-title" ).fadeOut(600);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.nav-bottom li').addClass('fade');
                        $( '.media-container' ).addClass( 'blur' );
                        $( '.overlay-title' ).addClass('reveal');

                    }, 800);

                    // button animation: contact -> close
                    $('.menu-contact').addClass('fade a-to-top');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // fade in the overlay container
                        $( ".content-wrapper-contact" ).removeClass( "fade" );

                        $('.btn-contact').addClass('off');
                        $('.btn-contact-close').removeClass('off');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('.menu-contact').removeClass('fade a-to-top');
                        }, 510);
                    }, 510);
            }
            else if (contact == false) {

                    // button animation: close -> contact
                    $('.menu-contact').removeClass('fade a-to-top');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // fade in the overlay container
                        $( ".content-wrapper-contact" ).addClass( "fade" );

                        $('.btn-contact').removeClass('off');
                        $('.btn-contact-close').addClass('off');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('.menu-contact').addClass('fade a-to-top');
                        }, 510);
                    }, 510);    
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script within

```
if (contact == true) { ...
```

only gets called when the page is loaded, not when the links are clicked. You could for example just move the code directly into the click functions, i.e.

```
// contact button
$(document).on('click', 'a.btn-contact', function(){

  // disable scrolling
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
  $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);

  setTimeout(function() {
    // switch to display block
    $( ".content-wrapper-contact" ).removeClass( "off" );
  }, 300);

  // fade out other elements
  $( '.container' ).addClass( 'blur' );
  $( ".content-wrapper" ).fadeOut(300);
  $( ".page-title" ).fadeOut(600);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.nav-bottom li').addClass('fade');
    $( '.media-container' ).addClass( 'blur' );
    $( '.overlay-title' ).addClass('reveal');

  }, 800);

  // button animation: contact -> close
  $('.menu-contact').addClass('fade a-to-top');
  setTimeout(function() {

    // fade in the overlay container
    $( ".content-wrapper-contact" ).removeClass( "fade" );

    $('.btn-contact').addClass('off');
    $('.btn-contact-close').removeClass('off');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.menu-contact').removeClass('fade a-to-top');
    }, 510);
  }, 510);

});

$(document).on('click', 'a.btn-contact-close', function(){

  // button animation: close -> contact
  $('.menu-contact').removeClass('fade a-to-top');
  setTimeout(function() {

    // fade in the overlay container
    $( ".content-wrapper-contact" ).addClass( "fade" );

    $('.btn-contact').removeClass('off');
    $('.btn-contact-close').addClass('off');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.menu-contact').addClass('fade a-to-top');
    }, 510);
  }, 510);  

});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/ek30omy4/).

Comment: Glad I could help!